# In flexbox, submit button is not working properly. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let formBtn = document.querySelector('#formBtn');

formBtn.addEventListener('click', function check_condition(){

let formName = document.querySelector('#formname').value;

if(formName == " "){
  alert("Kindly enter your name");
}

});
```

```css
.left-form{
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   gap: 16px;
   transition: all 0.6 ease;
}
.left-form h4{
    font-size: 26px;
}

.right-adrs{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: orange;
}

.form-inputs{
    padding: 12px 16px;
    color: lightgray;
    width: 90%;
}
#formBtn{
    width: 20%;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    background-color: #355E3B;
    color: white;
    border:#355E3B;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

textarea{
    height: 100px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-form">
        <h4>Get in touch</h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-inputs" id="formname" placeholder=" Name" />
            <input type="email" class="form-inputs formemail" placeholder=" Email"/>
            <input type="tel" class="form-inputs formtel" placeholder=" Phone number"/>
            <textarea placeholder=" Message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit"  id="formBtn">Send Message</button>
    </div>
```

I want to make a form in which the values can't go blank. If somebody clicks on button without entering the values, the alert box pops up. to design it, I have used flex property. but now the JavaScript is not working. Can somebody explain why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to the `flexbox`, that's happened because you check if the `formname` value is equal to empty space, but it should be an empty string `formName.trim() === ""` or `formName.length === 0`.

```js
let formBtn = document.querySelector('#formBtn');

formBtn.addEventListener('click', function check_condition(){
  let formName = document.querySelector('#formname').value;
  
  if(formName.trim() === ""){
    alert("Kindly enter your name");
  }
});
```

```css
.left-form{
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   gap: 16px;
   transition: all 0.6 ease;
}
.left-form h4{
    font-size: 26px;
}

.right-adrs{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: orange;
}

.form-inputs{
    padding: 12px 16px;
    color: lightgray;
    width: 90%;
}
#formBtn{
    width: 20%;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    background-color: #355E3B;
    color: white;
    border:#355E3B;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

textarea{
    height: 100px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-form">
        <h4>Get in touch</h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-inputs" id="formname" placeholder=" Name" />
            <input type="email" class="form-inputs formemail" placeholder=" Email"/>
            <input type="tel" class="form-inputs formtel" placeholder=" Phone number"/>
            <textarea placeholder=" Message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit"  id="formBtn">Send Message</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you please tell me why have you used '===' instead of '==' ?

Comment: You are welcome, In this situation will not effect the result if you used `==` or `===`, but by the way, the difference between them is type equality, for example `'1' == 1` will give a `true` value, but `'1' === 1` will give a `false` value, for more resouces you can read [this artice](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-triple-equals-sign-vs-double-equals-sign-comparison-operators-explained-with-examples/#:~:text=You%20may%20have%20seen%20double,checks%20for%20value%20equality%20only.)